# Background color blend, Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile

I have problem of not getting the correct background color for my app. I don't seem to understand how this works... In the Material App widget, I set up the background of my scaffolds, but the colors are not correct, so I need help with this..

main.dart:

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0E1324)),
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.id,
      routes: {
        SplashScreen.id: (context) => SplashScreen(),
      },
    );
```

I need to get this (Color(0xFF0E1324)) color:

[image: desired color]

but I keep getting this color blend:

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using that background color in an app and it looks correct to me

[imgur color pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upHGF.png)

Check if you have overridden the theme: scaffoldBackgroundColor by already specifying the color on the active Scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue, //Override theme scaffoldBackgroundColor
```